# How to connect css to html in Google Apps Scripts

Tags: html, css, google-apps-script

I'm trying to make my first Google App. I have my HTML doc which has the include statement as outlined on [HTML Service: Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices).

```
<html>
    <head>
        <base target="_top">
        <?!= include('stylesheet') ?>
    </head>
    <body>
       ...
    </body>
```

My code.gs file is as follows:

```
function doGet() {
   return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('BooksTS2.html')
  .evaluate();
}
```

My style sheet is named stylesheet.html, and for testing purposes is really simple:

```
<style>
   p {color: green;}
</style>
```

But when I run it I get this error message: ReferenceError: "include" is not defined.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the example they created the reusable function **include()**, you need to add it in your **code.gs** file:

```
function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .getContent();
}
```

You can always use the printing [scriptlet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#printing_scriptlets) directly in your html file like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <base target="_top">
    <?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('stylesheet').getContent(); ?>
    </head>
    <body>
       ...
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly what I needed.