# How to use Font Awesome in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, font-awesome

Environment is standalone script deployed as web app with `HTMLService()`:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate();
}

// see:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/39309690 
function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .getContent();
}
```

I can link to the Font Awesome css file in `index.html` like this:

```
<?!= include('css_font_awesome'); ?>
```

This will link to `css_font_awesome.html` which contains styles within `<style>` tags.

But how do I link to the `.eot`, `.woff`, `.ttf` and `.svg` files within the Font Awesome css file, ie:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.6.3');
  src: url('fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.6.3') format('embedded-opentype'), url('fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.6.3') format('woff2'), url('fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.6.3') format('woff'), url('fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.6.3') format('truetype'), url('fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.6.3#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use a CDN to include the FontAwesome stylesheet through the link tag.

Open the index.html and paste the following line in the head.

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: That worked, thanks, it would be good to know if it's possible without using a CDN (or any other external, non-google apps domain hosting), if any later posters comes across this.

Comment: As of 10/2016 there is no hosting option in Apps Script.  You would need to 3rd party host it.  Firebase,  App Engine, Cloud Storage are common ones used in the Apps Script community.